# Assigning IP to a bridged interfaces

Tags: linux, ip, bridge

Is there a way to assign an IP to bridged interfaces? For example, under normal circumstances:

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0
brctl addbr mybridge
brctl addif mybridge eth0
brctl addif mybridge eth1
```

So is there a way to either:

- (a) assign IPs to eth0/eth1?
- (b) if not, then is there any other way around this problem?

I want to some how bridge interfaces having IPs.

Answer (score 8):

You can directly assign a new IP address to your bridge:

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 brd + dev br0
```

You also may need to configure a route for the internet connection:

```
route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev br0
```

Note: replace the provided IP address in the above examples by the proper one for your subnet.

Comment: what does the `brd + dev` imply? I saw from [here](https://adam.younglogic.com/2020/12/adding-an-ip-address-to-a-bridge/) that it does have the `brd + ` part. While from [this page](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/blog/a-container-is-a-linux-namespace-and-networking-basics/) it uses your syntax.

Answer (score 2):

An interface that is a member of a bridge cannot have IPs assigned to it directly. You assign an address to the bridge interface instead, *e.g.*

```
ifconfig br0 0.0.0.0
```